# Flutter - Create a TextAlign animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I want to know if there is a way to animate text alignment just like you would do with AnimatedAlign widget.

In fact it would be nice if AnimatedDefaultTextStyle accept textAlign, like a Container with BoxDecoration overriding some fields from Container (but sadly it wont), please guys, im actualy very curious if this can be achieved.

```
AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: appState.textSize.value,
        color: Colors.white,
        ),
        curve: Curves.elasticOut,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        child: TextAnimator(
            hey,
            characterDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 8),
            incomingEffect: WidgetTransitionEffects.outgoingScaleUp(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100)),
            outgoingEffect: WidgetTransitionEffects.outgoingScaleUp(),
            textAlign: appState.textAlign.value //receives TextAlign.center/left/right,
         ),
```

in the case above, AnimatedDefaultTextStyle will animate any change on style:TextStyle();
and TextAnimator(its a package) will transition any string variable changes.

I expect some deep approach cause i couldn't find a answer to this in all internet or even pub.dev

Maybe extending TextAlign and inserting animations?

Thank you!

Doing research and after looked for third packages but i couldn't even scratch the tip of solving this, since i lack some experience in deeper finetuning flutter.

Edit 1:
I've researching and i created a somewhat possible solution:

- Make a custom widget, this widget will detect when text would override and break a new line.
- We will pick the part of the text that would be in the new line and put it in a new container simulating a new line and repeating the first process until we have containerized all lines.
- Then we could animate the container list like any other widget simulating a TextDirection change.

If somebody has experience in this i will gladly appreciate if you could help me on the part of line breaking and containerizing loop.

Edit 2:
For now i could start the tip of the idea:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slwC8.png)
Each line is inside a container, and the custom Widget receives only one big String and a maxWidth field.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating your own [ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget-class.html).

Since the parameter [AlignmentGeometry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AlignmentGeometry-class.html) contains a static method of lerp, the `AnimatedContainer` can evaluate the value from each tween controlled by this state with the specified visitor function. So in short, you need to add an extension for the TextAlign's static method for lerp too.

This can be a lot of work, but for me, you can use the existing `AlignmentGeometry` property from the AnimatedContainer and just create a custom extension that will convert the `TextAlign`'s value to `AlignGeometry` value.

Example:

```dart
extension TextAlignX on TextAlign {
  /// Converts this [TextAlign] to [AlignmentGeometry].
  AlignmentGeometry get toAlignGeometry {
    switch (this) {
      case TextAlign.left:
        return Alignment.centerLeft;
      case TextAlign.right:
        return Alignment.centerRight;
      case TextAlign.center:
        return Alignment.center;
      default:
        return Alignment.centerLeft;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Full Code:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

extension TextAlignX on TextAlign {
  /// Converts this [TextAlign] to [AlignmentGeometry].
  AlignmentGeometry get toAlignGeometry {
    switch (this) {
      case TextAlign.left:
        return Alignment.centerLeft;
      case TextAlign.right:
        return Alignment.centerRight;
      case TextAlign.center:
        return Alignment.center;
      default:
        return Alignment.centerLeft;
    }
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color color = Colors.black;
  TextAlign align = TextAlign.end;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.red;
      // Just to change the alignment randomly.
      align = TextAlign.values[Random().nextInt(4)];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedContainer(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.5),
              alignment: align.toAlignGeometry,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: color,
                  fontSize: 15,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: const Text('Animated Text Align'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, seems like a good approach! Could you please provide the code example?

Comment: sadly it didnt solve what i asked :(
in the end your approach are animating the container, not the text alignment. if you put a bigger text in this container you will understand what i mean, the line breaks and alignment direction wont change, so the container is the widget being controlled, not the TextAlign.

Comment: Still, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The only approach that I think will work based on your context is to create your own `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget`.

Comment: Ok thank you for the tip!